# How to balance bandwidth load in file streaming?

Tags: streaming, nginx, load-balancing

when it comes to stream big files it seems like nginx 1Gbps upload throughput link is small to handle transfer data from 3-4 storage servers.

The cause of my problem is bottle neck in proxy - all data go through loadbalancer.
Webservers downloading files from storage and streaming files over http (now through one nginx as loadbalancer).

Is it possible configure nginx to don't mediate in data streaming (static and dynamic data will be directly from webservers) and only balance requests? If not what shoud I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common used solution additional layer to dns loadbance and second solution is balancing in application layer in links. This problem is not yet fully resolved because of not monitored load, but can give extra bandwidth capacity by partitioning with this layers.